# Use of node-python to execute python scripts from web application hosted under python?

Tags: python, node.js

I've written python scripts for some numerical analysis topics and so I want to plot them in a nice way using any Java Script library.

So, I got to know about [python-node](https://npmjs.org/package/node-python) and they show some brief doc info at that site:

```
var python = require('node-python');
var os = python.import('os');

// nodejs stuff
var path = require('path');

assert(os.path.basename(os.getcwd()) == path.basename(process.cwd()))
```

However, how could I start to actually *do python*, import python libraries, run python scripts, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example show how to use `import` and call functions.

Try following:

```
var python = require('node-python');
var script = python.import('your_script_module_name');

script.your_function(argument1, argument2)
```

Comment: So I could even do more than one `script = python.import('your_script_module_name');` lines to keep coding, right?

Comment: I got module in same folder and I get: `Error: No module named python.taylorsum...`

Comment: @diegoaguilar, Did you set `PYTHONPATH=.` as I did in the screencast?

Comment: I did, yes, being `.` the folder from where such an *`app.js`* is being started

Comment: @diegoaguilar, Do you have a `python` directory in the same directory? If so, does `python` directory is a package (having `__init__.py`)?

Comment: No, I've got any python named directory :/

Comment: @diegoaguilar, Then, why do you try import `python.taylorsum` instead of `taylorsum` ?

Comment: Did, later moved them to same directory where PYTHONPATH is being set. Also removed python. prefix at import

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47107/discussion-between-falsetru-and-diegoaguilar)